# How to write CASE WHEN COUNT in HANA SQL

Tags: sql

The following column gives me counts:

```
COUNT("COMPLIANCE"."CD_ALL"."ProductCode") As "Active Contracts"
```

However, I want to put the count totals into buckets.  This is what I tried:

```
case when (COUNT("COMPLIANCE"."CD_ALL"."ProductCode")) between 0 and 10 then '10 or less',

case when (COUNT("COMPLIANCE"."CD_ALL"."ProductCode")) between 11 and 20 then '11-20',
```

and so on...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: add 'end' at the end of your case whens. before the comma ','

Comment: case when (COUNT("COMPLIANCE"."CD_ALL"."ProductCode")) between 0 and 10 then '10 or less' end,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a single `case` expression:

```
(case when (COUNT("COMPLIANCE"."CD_ALL"."ProductCode")) <= 10 then '10 or less'

      when (COUNT("COMPLIANCE"."CD_ALL"."ProductCode")) <= 20 then '11-20'
      else 'That many!!!'
end) as count_bucket
```